# EF core and creating a many to many table. Creates extra field. Why ?

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, ef-core-2.0

Why is there a UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristics.RefProgramCharacteristicsId field???  There should only be 2 fields not 3. Right? Below are the 3 classes and the OnModelCreating that is needed to create a many to many table

```
  public class RefProgramCharacteristic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProgramCharacteristic { get; set; }

     public List<UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic> UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristics { get; set; }

    // public ICollection<UserProgram> userPrograms { get; } = new List<UserProgram>();

   // public virtual ICollection<UserProgram> UserPrograms { get; set; }
}


  public class UserProgram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //UserProgramSaved
    public bool MyList { get; set; }
    public float MyPriorityRating { get; set; }
    public int Similarity { get; set; }
    public bool Compare { get; set; }

    //UserProgramSimilarity
    public int OverallSimilarityScore { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement1_WorkExp { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement2_VolExp { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement3_ResExp { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement4_Pubs { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement5_Step1 { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement6_Step2ck { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement7_Aoa { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement8_Nspecialties { get; set; }
    public int DeltaProfileElement9_PercentApps { get; set; }

    //UserComparisonSaved
    //  public RefProgramCharacteristic RefProgramCharacteristic { get; set; }
    public string RefProgramCharacteristicList { get; set; }


    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


    public int MedicalProgramId { get; set; }
    public RefProgramDetailData MedicalProgram { get; set; }


     public List<UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic> UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristics { get; set; }

   // public ICollection<RefProgramCharacteristic> RefProgramCharacteristics { get; } = new List<RefProgramCharacteristic>();

   // public virtual ICollection<RefProgramCharacteristic> RefProgramCharacteristics { get; set; }


}


   public class UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic
{
  //  public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserProgramId { get; set; }
    public UserProgram UserProgram { get; set; }


    public int RefProgramCharacteristicsId { get; set; }
    public RefProgramCharacteristic RefProgramCharacteristic { get; set; }
}


  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserProgramId, t.RefProgramCharacteristicsId });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

[image: Sql Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there a UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristics.RefProgramCharacteristicsId field?

Because you are telling EF Core to create such field here:

```
public int RefProgramCharacteristicsId { get; set; }
//                                 ^
```

While the navigation property is called `RefProgramCharacteristic` (no `s`). And [by EF Core conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions):

> If the dependent entity contains a property named **<primary key property name>**, **<navigation property name><primary key property name>**, or **<principal entity name><primary key property name>** then it will be configured as the foreign key.

`RefProgramCharacteristicsId` does not match any of these rules, so EF Core creates a shadow FK property with default name `RefProgramCharacteristicId`.

Either rename the property to `RefProgramCharacteristicId` (best), or map it explicitly using `ForeignKey` data annotation:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(RefProgramCharacteristicsId))]
public RefProgramCharacteristic RefProgramCharacteristic { get; set; }
```

or

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(RefProgramCharacteristic))]
public int RefProgramCharacteristicsId { get; set; }
```

or using `HasForeignKey` fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic>()
    .HasOne(e => e.RefProgramCharacteristic)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristics)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.RefProgramCharacteristicsId);
```